# Replace new lines at end of lines starting with pattern

Tags: sed

I have a file on my Ubuntu machine where I've marked the start of some lines using '@':

```
@A
bbb
@B
bbb
@D
ccc
```

I want to remove the new lines at the end of lines starting '@' so the above file becomes

```
@Abbb
@Bbbb
@Dccc
```

I can match the lines starting @ using sed:

```
sed /^@/ ...
```

but I'm lost at trying to find the way to remove the new line character at the end of the string.
There must be a way of doing this easily using `sed` without having to manually open the file in a text editor and remove them myself.

Comment: What operating system are you using? We need to know this so we can know what tools, and what implementations of tools, you have available.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, GNU sed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^@/j' ',p' 'Q' | ed -s file
@Abbb
@Bbbb
@Dccc
```

The above uses a short `ed` script to join each line in the file that matches the regular expression `^@` with the line after.  It then prints all the lines in the editing buffer and quits without saving.

---

```
$ sed '/^@/ { N; s/\n//; }' file
@Abbb
@Bbbb
@Dccc
```

This `sed` command appends the next line to the input buffer if the current line matches `^@`.  The inserted newline character is removed and the line printed.

Both of these variations would miss a line starting with `@` if it was immediately preceded by such a line.  This means, they would turn

```
@1
@2
X
@3
Y
```

into

```
@1@2
X
@3Y
```

rather than

```
@1@2X
@3Y
```

It is unclear whether this is ok or not.

Comment: The lines are broken due to faulty copy-paste from a MacOS terminal window to a (remote) Ubuntu 18.04 window hence why I added the "@" so I know where the lines are _supposed_ to start

Answer (score 4):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 'chomp if /^@/' -- file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each line after processing
- `/^@/` matches the `@` at the beginning of a line
- [chomp](http://p3rl.org/chomp) removes the trailing newline

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option with GNU `sed`:

```bsh
$ sed -E 'N;s/\n([^@])/\1/' foo.txt 
@Abbb
@Bbbb
@Dccc
```

Using the `N` flag:

> N
>
> ```
> appends line from the input file to the pattern space.
> ```

`([^@])` matches the firts character after the newline that is not a  `@`, capturing it and then adding it to the previous line.

If you need to modify the file you have to use the option `-i`: `sed -i...`, but make a backup first.

Answer (score 3):

Non-sed

1. if you know that all the lines alternate @ and non-@, then

   ```bsh
   paste -d '' - - < file
   ```
2. awk

   ```bsh
   awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/^@/ ? "" : ORS)}' file
   ```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(@.*)\n/\1/' file
@Abbb
@Bbbb
@Dccc
```

or

```
$ perl -pe 's/\n// if /^@/' file
@Abbb
@Bbbb
@Dccc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ printf "%s", (/^@/?(NR>1?ORS:""):"")$0 } END{ print "" }' infile
```

Sample input:

```
iiii
@A
bbb
xyz
@B
bbb
@D
ccc
```

Output:

```
iiii
@Abbbxyz
@Bbbb
@Dccc
```